# In pinescript, I have created a label for Buy Signal but it occurs frequently. But "ta.barsince" function not working as it returns (series) int

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4yCl.png)

I have created an indicator to generate "Buy/Sell" signal based on some criteria. But the indicator is giving frequent "Buy/Sell" signal which I want to avoid. What I want is that indicator gives next signal only after 10 bars.
Therefore I used "ta.barsince" function to return last bar where the signal (or condition met) is generated.

```
int lastGreenLabelBar = ta.barssince(greenWeight >= threshHold and volumeStrength >= 1.3)
```

and then use the value of 'lastGreenLabelBar' to satisfy my condition.

```
if greenSignal and volumeStrength >= 1.3 and lastGreenLabelBar > 10
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = low - (low * percDist / 100), text = message, color=color.black, textcolor=color.lime, style=label.style_label_up, size=size.normal)
```

But the condition lastGreenLabelBar > 10 never returns true despite the fact that lastGreenLabelBar shows >10 values many times (when displayed with plotchar()).

I have searched on the web and find that "ta.barsince" returns (series) int which is different from int, and series int values cannot be converted into normal int.

Is the problem can be solved using "ta.barsince"? If not then please suggest some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the old way.

Have a `var` counter and reset it when you plot your label. Increment it by 1 otherwise.

This should do:

```
var my_barssince = 0

my_barssince := my_barssince + 1

if greenSignal and volumeStrength >= 1.3 and my_barssince > 10
    my_barssince := 0
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = low - (low * percDist / 100), text = message, color=color.black, textcolor=color.lime, style=label.style_label_up, size=size.normal)
```